# restricting sms to go into inbox

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I need to restrict sms not to save in inbox. and it should be saved in some user given folder.For that im using bellow code. i can able to restrict sms notification. by using this.abortBroadCast() in my receiver clas.. But SMS is showing in Inbox.
I need restrict it entering into INBOX. And it shoulb shown in some other folder.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //this stops notifications to others   
        this.abortBroadcast(); 

        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        boolean checksomething =true ;
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }

        }                      

        if(checksomething){  
             Toast.makeText(context, "Broad Cast Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{       
            this.clearAbortBroadcast();    
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what platform you're using.

Comment: i need this application for android 2.2 and above

Answer (score 1):

Just on the manifest must increase the priority of your Intent, as follows:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
<intent-filter android:priority="100"> 
    <action android:name=
        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF YOU WANT TO RESTRICT THE MESSAGE TO GO TO OTHER APPS STORAGE YOU HAVE TO SET THE "PRIORITY" OF YOUR APP IN nadroid.manifst... HERE IN
   THIS CASE I AM BLOCKING MY OWN SMS TO GO TO MY SMS APPS STORAGE.

=====================================================================

*Code in SMSBROAD CAST RECEIVER CLASSS.*

```
  if(sender.equalsIgnoreCase("+923339736506"))
    {
       Toast.makeText(context, "you are not allowed ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.abortBroadcast();
      }
```

and setting the priority in android.manifest like this

```
       <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 

        <intent-filter android:priority="100"> 

        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 

        </intent-filter> 

    </receiver>
```